# Elementor semi-full width navbar boxed container (example given)

Tags: css, menu, elementor

Hello Elementor users,

I would like to know how to make a header like the website given in the example below:

https://demo.templatemonster.com/nl/demo/69483.html?_gl=1*1q812us*_ga*OTEyMTI5OTAwLjE2OTQ3OTg1MjE.*_ga_FTPYEGT5LY*MTY5NDg0NzYwMy40LjEuMTY5NDg0ODQzNC4zMS4wLjA.&_ga=2.115414721.651636356.1694798521-912129900.1694798521&_gac=1.255463034.1694806788.CjwKCAjwgZCoBhBnEiwAz35Rwn2VeINVwM8JWl0WO18HKoE0Tt8fWywywZGZOP9R_YZAHzElZKBIcRoCxQQQAvD_BwE

https://audisleutelbijmaken.nl/

I recreated the header but I am not sure if this is the right way with responsiveness in mind. Is there any other way to make this header? I would like to skew the side like I did but with the height of the ::before and ::after that scales with the orange column. Now it's just a height given of 64 px but if I scale the page, it gets all messy.

I am trying for days now and this is the furthest I have came.

Thanks in advance :)